Apple in-App Redemption sheet does not dissmiss automatically or on Open Application button click in Swift
I'm using Swift 5 and the proper method to present the redemption sheet. However, once I redeem the code in debug mode redemption sheet dismisses correctly and showing a purchase success alert. But when I'm trying it on the published App, it shows "Open Application" button after successful redemption and it does not dismiss even after clicking on the button or didnot dissmiss auto automatically. Here is my method of displaying the offer redemption sheet.
@MainActor
    static func showRedemptioncodeWindow() {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first {
            Task {
                do {
                    print("===> showRedemptioncodeWindow - presenting Redemption code UI")
                    try await AppStore.presentOfferCodeRedeemSheet(in: window as! UIWindowScene)
                    try await StoreKit.AppStore.presentOfferCodeRedeemSheet(in: window as! UIWindowScene)
                    
                } catch {
                    print("====> show Redemption window, ", error)
                }
            }
        }
    }

